# sp_BlitzIndex missing index gone after removing unused indexes

Tags: sp-blitzindex

I recently watched the sp_Blitzindex video and testing the tool found most of our tables had a combination of missing indexes and also indexes which have hundreds of writes and no reads. I think that means we should remove those with no reads.

Anyway we removed the first one and then ran the sp_Blitzindex againand the missing index wasn't shown.

Does this mean removing the not needed index resets the cache? Should we do it the otehr way around? Add the missing first, then delete the redundant indexes?

Attached screenshots to illustrate what happened.

[image: sp_Blitzindex before and after removing index]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you make index changes to a table, SQL Server resets the missing index suggestions for that table.